# How to fix connection error after installing Sql server

Tags: sql-server

I had the following error message in Visual Studio when I am trying to connect to [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server):

I got this message

```
> A network-related or instance-specific error
>occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>The server was not found or was not accessible.
>Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>(provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could
>not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

This occurred when I was trying to setup SQL Management studio, but as always I face problems setting it up. Now I can't use either of them.

How do I fix this up?

Comment: Hm. Bad Pizza when programming. See, I program and I had a pizza that tasted terribly. Why? Same with your thing - the error CLEARLY points to "visual studio has ZERO relevance". Please spend more than 1 second thinking of a subject line.

Comment: Yeah I think so

Answer (score 2):

Usually that means you either typed the server name incorrectly, or that the server does not have the SQL Server service running. Check those two things.

Comment: Or that the firewall blocks such connections.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite common issue. Take a look at existing answers on Stack Overflow, for example, *[How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409)*.