# error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Hi I'm writing a simple console application to save XML data into the database using bulkcopy but am currently having problems connecting to my database.

I am getting a SqlException error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have checked for issues ensuring my SQL server is running and that it's configured correctly. Below is my connection string.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=SYAZANA;Initial Catalog=WangSCM;integrated security=true;" ;
```

I'm at my wits ends trying to figure out the error, what is the mistake that I'm making?

Comment: Is the SQL Server on the same machine as the program or not? If not, check your firewall on the SQL Server side. Port 1433 (default instance) should be open at least. https://support.microsoft.com/de-ch/kb/968872/en-us for more ports used by SQL Server

Comment: @Scoregraphic thank you for the reply, yes they're on the same machine and i've checked that it's port 1433

Comment: @zana Please upvote and accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the steps:**

*Go to SQL Server Configuration manager

*SQL Server Network Configuration:

*Protocol for MSSQLSERVER

*In the right pane split page you will have to disable VIA as follows

--->Shared Memory - Enable

--->Named Pipes - Enable

--->TCP/IP - Enable

--->VIA - Disable

**Or   Try the following**

Go to Start -> in search type `Services.msc`. There you will find services which are available in your system.

There look for -> **SQL EXPRESS / `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`** -> Right click on it -> then **Start** it .
If it is already in Start. Just **Stop** and **start** or simply **Restart** it.

Comment: I have tried this before but it didnt work

Comment: I just restarted it but it is still unsuccessful :(

Comment: i think restarting your system may help you. just try for it..

Comment: @ReyanChougle oh, I'm sorry. I'm not the one who raised the question. any way 1+ ..

Comment: it works too! +1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for some reason I had to add the standard SQL port (1433) and then everything worked again. In your case that would be:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=SYAZANA,1433;Initial Catalog=WangSCM;integrated security=true;"
```