# Spun up a Windows 2016 Server with SQL Express on LightSail and Can Not Connect to SQL using IP Address

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-lightsail

I can not connect to he SQL Server Express using the provided Static IP Address.  I have tried:

1. Making sure that it accepts Remote Connections
2. Updating and setting the SA Username and Password
3. Made sure TCP/IP and Named Pipes are Enabled
4. Configured firewall (and even turned it off while testing)
5. Made sure SQL Express Browser was running
6. Went Under "IP All" and removed TCP Dynamic Port and set TCP Port to 1433.
7. RESTARTED the SQL Server engine (several times)

But still get the error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Anyone have ANY suggestions?  I would like to use the IP address as my connection.

Comment: Have you tried searching for solutions? e.g. this comes up straight away: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143486/microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-named-pipes-provider-could-not-open-a , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995047/sql-server-error-named-pipes-provider-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-serve

Comment: Yes, I have looked at both of those pages.  And have followed them but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry to have wasted everyone's time.

I was trying to connect on a WiFi Network at a hotel that DID NOT allow connections like this, most likely for security reasons.

Once I was back on my work wifi -- I connected just fine.

I am putting this answer here just in case someone finds themselves in the same boat.