# oracle connection into c# ssis script task

Tags: c#, oracle, ssis, connection

I have a connection manager that points to an oracle database.I then need to use that said connection into a ssis script task.I don't know how to proceed.I tried something and I got an error message could you help me.Here is my code: I also tried with those connection string:

```
// SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SOURCE;User ID=user_GG;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;");
SqlConnection oracleConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PRONMPIA;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=yes;");
oracleConn.Open();

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM random.table", oracleConn))
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int name = reader.GetInt32(0);
        MessageBox.Show("SALUT " + name.ToString() );
    }
}
oracleConn.Close();

MessageBox.Show(" test succes");
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: What error message did you receive ?

Comment: (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Impossible to open a connexion to sql server). A error due to network or specific to the instqance happened while trying to establish a connexion  to sql server.The server was not found or is not accessible. Sorrry I had to translate the error message.

Comment: Try troubleshooting via: [how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `SqlConnection` which is a .Net component for SQL Server, not for Oracle. You need the `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and the `OracleConnection`. To use that you need to add the Oracle .Net provider to the `References` of the `Script` task (see project explorer References node when editing the script task .Net code), Add  `Oracle.DataAccess`, then in you code "`using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;`". HTH