# How to connect Laravel and Microsoft sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

Here is my configuration in laravel:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.15'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'gaspos'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'vlado'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test1'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

And when I try:

php artisan migrate, I get:

```
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Prov
  ider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
```

Anyone know what is porblem?

Comment: Did you put all your SQL Serve credentials in `.env` file?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195566)?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec

Comment: hello, how are you? I wanna also laravel+microsoft sql server configuration. Do  you fix this problem? If yes, can you help me, please?