# SQL Server access database same domain, different computer

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I've been trying to install a SQL Server database at my office. For this I created a new database in SQL Server Management Studio and I created a login for the server. I created a user in the database for this login and a password.

When I try to access this database with this user it works perfectly on my computer but when I try with the same connection string on an other computer connected to the domain it does not work.

The error message I'm getting is :

> error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Here is the connection string I'm using :

```
Data Source=2PSVRG3;Initial Catalog=dbName;User ID=userName;Password=******
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Have you looked [here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: Yes I've tried everything on that post but it does not change, it looks like the connection to 2PSVRG3 doesn't work. It's SQL Server 2014 btw.

Comment: What are you using to connect? some kind of client application? Can yo try this https://www.sophos.com/support/knowledgebase/65525.aspx and confirm that you get the same message. Can you go to a command prompt and type `PING 2PSVRG3` What happens?

Comment: When I do this i get the message :
Packets : Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0

Answer (score 3):

If this is an Sql Server Express Edition check your configuration manager's network configuration whether TCP/IP is enabled and the SQL Server browser services is enabled and running