# SQLServerManager13.msc not present in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. i.e. Where is my SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, database-connection

I want to configure my Microsoft SQL Server to enable named pipes, because right now I get this error when I try to connect to my projects database on Azure:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or
>   was not accesible. Verify the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error:40 - could not open a connection to SQL server)
>   The network path was not found

In quest to solve the problem I have found some resource:

- [How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec) here on SO.
- [How to Fix named Pipes Provider Error 40 cannot open connection to Sql server instance](http://www.microsoft-sql-ssis.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-named-pipes-provider-error.html)
- [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) on msdn.microsoft.com
- [Where is sql configuration manager in windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/997663/where-is-sql-configuration-manager-in-windows-10)

The conclusion seems to be I need to access the SQL Server Configuration Manager to enable Named Pipes and some other stuff. Problem is, I can't find it on my system.

I have checked C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for

- SQL Server 2016 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc
- SQL Server 2014 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager12.msc
- SQL Server 2012 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc
- SQL Server 2008 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc

It is not there.

I use the newest version of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, everything installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to open needed endpoints on the Azure portal? They should be opened in the VM firewall as well. I think that you have that issue because of that.
[That](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-connect/) can be used for a setup reference.

UPD from the chat: as we found, the used database is the SQL Azure and can be connected from the first location and from the second. Should be the issue with the IPs.

Comment: The link you provide also suggests  that I "1. While connected to the virtual machine, on the Start page, type SQL Server Configuration Manager and hit ENTER." which is my whole problem: It doesn't exist on my machine. Or if it does, I cannot locate by following the guides I have linked to.

Comment: @MartinJH let's chat a little? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111561/sqlserveronazure

Comment: @MartinJH so, please try to add your IP to the SQL Azure DB and see if that is helps :)

Comment: Adding the IP still leaves me with the 40 error. But if you'll add the link to the SQL Server Management Studio installation page, I'll accept your answer, since installing the studio adds the SQLServerManager13.msc to the SysWOW64.

Comment: Actually working on it right now. I've made sure I'm owner of the database, so now I can work on it directly. But even as admin, and firewall accepting my ip, I still can't get it to work. Right now I'm trying to fiddle with the connection string.

Comment: Did you check if your workplace/homeplace is not blocking ports/etc?

Comment: My homeplace might do. It's an apartment complex with a shared network. I know another programmer living here who has to use a VPN to make his server connect with some other API I think

Comment: I would check with your network admin or provider. Likely, the ports needed (1433/1434) are blocked

Comment: I'll Check up on it. Also, I'll try with an VPN to see if that can fix it. Will be reporting back :)

Comment: Success! I gained instant access by using the https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn vpn service and adding my recieved ip to the azure firewall. So the problem was my homeplace's network provider all along. Thanks so much for the help Alex. I'll accept your current answer as correct, but please update it to reflect our findings. But I can do it for you by all means. It's the least I can do for all the fantastic help you have provided. Again, thank you very much for all your time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

1.I encountered the same issue while installing SQL Server 2017 & was unable to login to SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) 2018.I then checked the background services running and couldn't see any SQL Server components.

2.The problem was I didn't correctly install the SQL Server Database Engine, to do so use the Installation Wizard (Setup) from the official website. You can get it here [SQL Server Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)

> The Database Engine component of SQL Server is the core service for
>   storing, processing, and securing data. Without it you cannot run SQL Server.

3.And therefore SQL Server has something known as **'SQL Server Configuration Manager'**.

SQL Server Configuration Manager is a tool to manage the services associated with SQL Server, to configure the network protocols used by SQL Server, and to manage the network connectivity configuration from SQL Server client computers.

4.To achieve a breakthrough you need to install(again) SQL Server properly in your machine after which you can search for the file in the file explorer

- SQL Server 2017- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc
- Also all the services running *(The one highlighted is the core service of the Database Engine component of SQL Server)* 
  [image: Core Database Engine/Service of SQL]

  For more information on SQL Server Configuration Manager and where to find it click here:  [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I could find it here: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager15.msc"
SQL Server 2019