# Can't connect to tbe server in Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, management-studio-express

When i try to connect to the server in Microsoft Management Studio 2014 i get this error.

The error that is being shown:-

[image]

I have followed many articles in order to eradicate my problem but i am unable to resolve it. Whenever i browse for more servers nothing appears in the local servers.

No options are available in the local servers:-

[image]

I have checked if 'SERVER' is being run in the *Services* section aswell.

Kindly assist me with this issue. I thought there is some issue with the installation so i tried both the version Management studio 2012 and 2014.

Comment: Could you please check this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec

Comment: Have installed SQL Server first?  If yes,Have you enabled TCP/IP from configuration Manager?

Comment: @apomene Thanks alot i got that done and there was some issue with my server so i reinstalled it and it started working fine. Thanks for the help.