# The network path was not found in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a question regarding unable to access remote database in my website web config file.

A network related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

connectionStrings

Comment: <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=56.192.68.4;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User ID=sa;Password=***********"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: try to add Integrated security=sspi in your connection string and check

Comment: It is occured because you lost the connection to the database. Try to reload/refresh your page.

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicate questions. The error is clear - you can't even connect to the server. The reasons are always the same: you are using the wrong server name or address, or the server is down, or the server's firewall prevents remote connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On server check
1. Named pipes/TCP is enabled
2. Firewall configured for incoming connections

On Client Check
1. Can you reach the server by Ping
2. Can you connect using SQL management studio
3. Check if antivirus or firewall blocking the port

[Similar question is answered earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: 1. Enable Named Pipes: SQL Config Manager -> SQL Server Network Consif -> Protocols -> Named Pipes -> Right-click -> Restart    2. firewall config: Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, on Inbound Rules, New Rule -> select Port-> select TCP. type 1433 for the default instance. -> Allow the connection ... finish ... full description is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: in my case, need to open port 1443