# SQL Server 2014 connection error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

The following error occured while trying to connect to SQL Server 2014 in Visual Studio 2015; the instace name is same

[image]

Connection string used:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\aspnet-test-20170‌​805104353.mdf;Initia‌​l Catalog=aspnet-test-20170805104353;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: **SHOW US** your conenction string! Obviously, something is wrong with your connection string....

Comment: If your connection string is correct please check this http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx

Comment: Your connection string looks good. But have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: @T.Jung Sql Server services are running