# A network related or instance-specific error occurred - sql server.(error: 40 - cound not open a connectiion to sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

[image]
[image]

> A network related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to sql server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   sql server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: named
>   pipes provider, error: 40 - cound not open a connectiion to sql
>   server)

Ok, I've tried everything.
http://support.sysonline.com/support/solutions/articles/4000016491-errmsg-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql

I actually though is my Firewall; so I add the exceptions and even tried to disable the firewall. Though non of it is working; I've spend hours on youtube too.

Scenario:

- I have an application developed with VB.net; which the installer
  (Setup.exe) is made.
- msSql is use an an external database.
- Connect connecting is using **Windows Authentication**
- I installed **SQLExpress 2017 from Microsoft Website.**
- Installed **SQL Server Management Studio 17**

  - Installed **Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime CTP**
  - Installed **SQLSYSCLRTYPES.msi (x64)**
- MS .NET Framework 4.5 - 4.5.2
- MS .NET Framework 4.5.1

What I am still missing?
I've checked my **Service.exe** to ensure that SQLExpress is running & also in **SQL Server 2017 Configuration Management** that SQLExpress is running as well everytime.

What is likely to be in the way? The **Database is in the local Device computer (on the same computer) with the deveoped application software**

~~~~~~~

Question 2:
So If I *install the SETUP.EXE of the application*, W**here will the installed location will be**? Maybe I can change it in this MANIFEST File.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Question 3:

> > Installation Guideline
> >     -------------------------------- Step 1:
>
> -Installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012
>   -Open SQL Server Management Studio
>   -Create User or Login into SQL Authentication
>
> Step 2:
>
> -right-click database and select restore database
>   -select device and find a file called RMS.bak
>   -Then press ok or confirm button
>
> Step 3:
>
> -Create a new user for SQL login
>   -Select Security -> Login and right click select new user Enter following : In General or Example: a) Login name = Tho b) Select SQL
>   Server Authentication c) Password = thopass d) Mark = enforece
>   password policy     enforce password expiration
>             In Server Roles e) mark = public      sysadmin
>
> In User mapping a) mark all the map  b) User = Database : All user and
>   RMS     User : Tho      default Schema : dbo c) Every user map login ->
>   Database role membership for model    mark = db_owner
>            public
>
> After finish all press ok button... Login using thomas to try login
>
> Install Application 1) Double click setup  2) Select type: ClickOnce
>   Application name: RestManagementSys

Do anyone **what does Step 3 meants?** I just can't understand it. It's for MSSQL connection establishment (i think so).

Comment: What is that "everything" you tried? What is the connection string? That error is pretty clear - either you are using the *wrong* server name or there's no server running. It's easy to fix too. Fix the connection string if it's wrong, start the server if it's down. BTW YouTube isn't a configuration tool. You don't need a video to install SQL Server

Comment: BTW have you tried the simplest thing, connecting from SSMS? Did you try to browse for servers? If the database is installed locally it will appear under the `Local` node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: Yes, "connecting from SSMS?" -> I've use the [SQL Server Management Studio 17] to restore and connect to the database.

Comment: restore? Then you already connected once? Or do you mean you want to restore once you connect? And what does `Yes` mean? What address did you use? Did you select `Browse` in the drop down?

Comment: My previous HDD was broken/spoilded . So I have the .bak for the Database.
The data is indeed in the database. So I choose to restore the DB into using the current [SQL Server Management Studio 17].

I've just added the picture to the post. I hope it may provide some clarity.. i guess.

Comment: I'll check out the link that you've suggested. I really appreciate your help. while I am not sure if the suggested link will help, I'll try anything that is out there.

thank you very much.

Comment: ok, didn't seems to helped. hmm..

Comment: ok, I manage to get some lead.

Comment: The problem I have is not something that can be solve with those typical solution that is given online. The root cause is actually related to the [LINQ to SQL Classes] whereby in the "Data Source = {String}" ; where {String} / instant is NOT Equal to the current Instant on this PC.

So If I install the SETUP.EXE of the application, Where will the installed location will be? Maybe I can change it in this MANIFEST File.