# SqlServer2012-Error 40-Could not open a connection in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know this is an answered question , however I have tried all the steps mentioned
like:

1. In SQL Configuration manager have Enabled  TCP/IP,Shared Memory and Named Pipes.
2. Restarted the SQLSERVER
3. In Services.msc I have restarted SQLSERVER and SQL Server Agent
4. Added port 1433 in firewall's Inbound rule
5. Restarted PC number of times
6. Even Registered Local Server in SQL Server Management tools

I can open SQL Server Management tools
It was working fine and now its not. However I am able to login , then I cannot do any work on it, it gives me an error as :
[image]

Tried all the steps mentioned in the accepted answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)
I have some other application accessing same SQL Server and they are working fine.
My Connection string :

```
public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RMS_EXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxx");
```

I also tried with the following connection string

```
Data Source=.;Database=RMS_TS1;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxxx
```

It gave me an error. "Login Failed for User 'sa'"

My application and Database are on the same PC

So , please help.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not setup in your connection string both `Integrated Security=true` and `User Id=sa;Password=xxxxxx`

`Integrated Security = true` means it is using windows credentials (of the user the application is running into). A database connection cannot use both windows AND SQL Server authentication.

You should either:

- Use `Integrated Security=true` and do not specify User Id nor password. This would use windows authentication.
- Use `Integrated Security=false` or remove it althogether and specify both `User Id` and `Password`. This would use SQL Server user/password authentication.

Besides that, there was an adittional problem, originally you put `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS` but had to access default instance via `Data Source=.` which caused that error.

Comment: You're completely right but this will certainly not cause the error mentioned

Comment: This is strange. In the question mark says `"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"` but in his last comment says `"Data Source=.;"` Maybe he should read about sql server instances, that could really cause the error mentioned.

Comment: @bradbury9 it worked I put in `Data Source=.;Database=RMS_TS1;Integrated Security=True` Thanks

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Edited the answer to add the second problem, the one causing the error mentioned.

Comment: So after all that... there was no technical issue. The problem was that the wrong hostname was in the connection string.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it was same earlier it worked,suddenly it was not connecting. Dont know what happened what caused it

Comment: I'm not trolling or arguing here, just saying it would appear then that this answer did not solve your  question. That's fine. There's probably enough value in this question to just keep it this way.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid If you think it can be improved changing the order of the paragraphs and putting more enphasis on the last one (the one that addresses the instance name, because the hostname was ok) feel free to submit an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Allow Remote Connections enabled under Connections in SQL Server Properties.

Comment: from where I can enable this, through SQL Server Configuration manager?

Comment: First open SQL Management Studio then right click on the server name on the left hand side and click on the server Properties.

Comment: `.\SQLEXPRESS`. It's a *local* instance.