# Entity Framework: DBContext can't connect to server on another PC when deployed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, deployment, dbcontext

I created a model from DbContext and stored connection string in the app config file. It runs perfectly on my PC. However when I deploy it to another PC, it throws an exception

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections.
>
> (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server
>   )

```
public  class FoodIndustryContext:DbContext
    {
        public FoodIndustryContext (): base("name = FoodIndustryContextDB") { }
        public DbSet<Industry> Industries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
    }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name = "FoodIndustryContextDB"
       connectionString = "Data Source =.;Initial Catalog = FoodIndustryDemo;Integrated Security = true"
       providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `Data Source=.` means the local computer. I assume where you deployed your app does not also have the database.

Comment: I don't understand you well @Crowcoder

Comment: It works on your PC because you have the database server ON YOUR PC. When you put the application on another computer the connection string is looking for the datbase on *itself* but there is no database installed on itself. The `Data Source` attribute usually has a server name instead of just `.`.

Comment: @Kinyo356 are your database and application in different computer?

Comment: It worked perfectly as you said @Crowcoder. I changed Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0. Please re-write it as an answer, let me accept it as the correct answer. And also, if you have any other suggestion of what the data source should be.

Comment: No @TanvirArjel. I just wanted to see how it will work on another PC

Comment: this question indeed has nothing to do with entity framework.

Comment: You can't expect Local db to be installed on a general user's computer so you may run into trouble yet still. If you intend for the database to always be local instead of a central dedicated server then you will have to handle installing it too.

Answer (score 0):

if you take remote sql server, you have to enable firewall of the remote system.

See following link. 
[How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

Comment: One problem at a time. OP doesn't even have a database server.