# Cannot connect to ANY remote SQL Servers from my system

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot connect to any remote SQL Server instances from my system. I used to connect them from SQL Server Management Studio. Moreover, I can still connect to the same SQL Servers remotely from another systems (my colleagues' system).

I am getting following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> Error Number: 53
> Severity: 20
> State: 0

I have checked:

1. Named pipes/TCP is enabled.
2. Remote connections are allowed.
3. Windows Firewall is off.
4. Enabled everything in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Also, I have tried everything mentioned in this post-

[How do I fix the error 'Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to' SQL Server'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec)

But still could not solve my problem. Please suggest any method which allows me to fix this error and connect to the remote servers again.

Comment: See [Solving Connectivity errors to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/topic/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server-ae23c94b-b64b-5056-8b62-22e1694bb889?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Talk to the people that manage your network as well as those that manage the machines on which your remote database server instances are running. If your local machine is configured correctly, then the problem must be "upstream" of your machine.

Comment: So for example if your machine name is DBServer and you are using default instance MSSQLSERVER, then you can simply connect to that instance either by specifying server name DBServer or (local) or . a dot

Answer (score 0):

instead of check whether that server system is working or not, because sometimes if the server system is not working means we are unable to connect to that system