# Cannot connect to localhost - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a new machine, and I'm trying to connect to my localhost using Windows Authentication in SSMS.

This has worked on all my previous machines, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot connect to localhost.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server 
is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

------------------------------

The system cannot find the file specified
```

I assume there's something I need to turn on or some setting I need to change, just not sure what it is.

Comment: Post the connection information you're trying to use (assuming the SQL Server instance is running).

Comment: Did you install the actual SQL Server database engine?

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945409/how-do-i-fix-the-error-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connec